# build-list (error - expects a procedure) Racket/Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Trying to make a function that produces a n by n board

```
(new-board 2)
```

is supposed to produce

```
(list (make-posn 0 0) (make-posn 0 1) (make-posn 1 0) (make-posn 1 1))
```

The current rendition of my code is as follows:

```
(define (new-board y)
    (build-list y (lambda (x) (build-list x (make-posn y x))))
      )
```

I was pretty certain that it would work, but given my current knowledge and experience in Racket, I couldn't find the error.

I typed in:

```
> (new-board 3)
```

and got the error:

```
build-list: expects a procedure (arity 1); given (make-posn 3 0)
```

Am I committing a heinous crime by invoking build list inside of a build-list?
Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About this procedure:

```
(define (new-board y)
    (build-list y (lambda (x) (build-list x 
                                          (make-posn y x))))) ;error!
```

Let's see what [`build-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html#%28def._%28lib._htdp-intermediate-lambda..rkt._lang%29._%28%28lib._lang/htdp-intermediate-lambda..rkt%29._build-list%29%29) receives as parameters. The first parameter is `y`, a number and the second parameter is a procedure, but you're passing **the result of evaluating `make-posn`**, which is not a procedure, it's a value. And that's the reason for the error you're getting.

**EDIT 1 :**

Now I understand what you intended. I can think of a solution, but it's a bit more elaborated than what you had in mind:

```
(define (new-board n)
  (flatten
   (map (lambda (x)
          (map (lambda (y)
                 (make-posn x y))
               (build-list n identity)))
        (build-list n identity))))

(define (flatten lst)
  (if (not (list? lst))
      (list lst)
      (apply append (map flatten lst))))
```

Here's how it works:

- `build-list` is just being used for generating numbers from `0` to `n-1`, and I'm passing `identity` as the procedure, because no further processing is required for each number
- For each number in the list, we also want to generate another list, again from `0` to `n-1` because all the coordinates in the board are required. For example if `n` is 3 the coordinates are `'((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (2 0) (2 1) (2 2))`
- I'm using a `map` inside a `map` for building the nested lists, a technique borrowed from [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3) (see: "nested mappings")
- Finally, I had to flatten the generated lists, and that's what `flatten` does (otherwise,   we'd have ended with a list of lists of lists)

**EDIT 2 :**

Come to think of it, I found an even simpler way, closer to what you had in mind. Notice that the `flatten` procedure is unavoidable:

```
(define (new-board n)
  (flatten
   (build-list n
               (lambda (x)
                 (build-list n
                             (lambda (y)
                               (make-posn x y)))))))
```

Now, when you type this:

```
(new-board 2)
```

The result is as expected:

```
(#(struct:posn 0 0) #(struct:posn 0 1) #(struct:posn 1 0) #(struct:posn 1 1))
```

Comment: Ah, guess it was a mistake to leave out the overall intention of the program. This is the prelude to solving the n-Queens problem. Although I wasn't yet prepared to do so since I still couldn't manage to work out the kinks in this simple program.

and yes, it is supposed to produce a list of posns. Although I can totally see why you would ask that! :P

Comment: @WhiteBit anyway, you should post the code of `build-list` and `make-posn`, otherwise we're left in the dark

Comment: Also, build-list is a built-in function. (build-list n proc) → list

(build-list 5 add1) will produce (list 1 2 3 4 5)
//

(make-posn n n) creates a structure posn with two Nums.
(i typically use it as a associative array, but this time it's used to represent the tiles on the board.)

Comment: @WhiteBit I overlooked that fact. I edited my answer, now the error is clear. Please post `make-posn`, and an example of what exactly is the output you expect from `new-board` - the list `(list (make-posn 0 0) (make-posn 0 1) (make-posn 1 0) (make-posn 1 1))` or the _result_ of evaluating `make-posn` for each element in the list

Comment: I think the reason why (make-posn) sounds so foreign could be that it was only introduced in How To Design Programs' Beginning Student - scheme. Well, here's make-posn. make-posn : (number number -> posn). Probably defined like this : (define-struct posn (x y)) where x and y are numbers. Hope that clears it up. Thanks for your time Oscar!

Comment: @WhiteBit There, I added a working solution. I hope it's not too complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the signature (contract) of `build-list`[1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html#%28def._%28lib._htdp-intermediate-lambda..rkt._lang%29._%28%28lib._lang/htdp-intermediate-lambda..rkt%29._build-list%29%29), you see that it is

```
 build-list : Nat (Nat -> X) -> (listof X)
```

So it takes a (natural) number, and then a *function* that expects a natural number and gives back an element of the type (X) that you want included in the list. So in your case, what specific type do you want X to be for each call you're making to `build-list` (it can be different in each case). In the case of the inner `build-list`, it looks like you're trying to make a list of `posn`s. However, `(make-posn y x)` immediately makes a single `posn` and is not a function as `build-list` expects. So just as you provide a function `(lambda (x) ...)` to the outer `build-list`, you should also provide a function `(lambda (...) ...)` to the inner function.

Choosing the name `x` for the parameter of the first `lambda` might be a little confusing. What I might do is change the name of the `new-board` function's parameter to N, in that it seems like you want to create a board of `N` rows (and columns). And the purpose of the first `build-list` is to create each of those rows (or columns, depending how you want to think of it). So if you had:

```
 (define (new-board N)
   (build-list N (lambda (x) ...)))
```

And then you use it like:

```
 (new-board 5)
```

it will reduce/simplify/evaluate as follows:

```
 ==> (build-list 5 (lambda (x) ...))
 ==> (list ( (lambda (x) (build-list ... x ...))  0 )
           ( (lambda (x) (build-list ... x ...))  1 )
           ( (lambda (x) (build-list ... x ...))  2 )
           ( (lambda (x) (build-list ... x ...))  3 )
           ( (lambda (x) (build-list ... x ...))  4 )
 ==> (list (build-list ... 0 ...)
           (build-list ... 1 ...)
           (build-list ... 2 ...)
           (build-list ... 3 ...)
           (build-list ... 4 ...))
```

So, there's nothing wrong with nesting `build-list`. See if you can figure out now how to have the inner build-list work on producing a list of posns once the current row is fixed to a particular `x` value.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you're allowed to use full Racket, there's a nice way to express the computation with `for` loops:

```
(define (new-board n)
  (for*/list ([i n]
              [j n])
    (make-posn i j)))
```

Another way to get the same result but with a different approach is to use an arithmetic trick with `quotient` and `remainder`.

```
(define (new-board n)
  (build-list (* n n)
              (lambda (k)
                (make-posn (quotient k n)
                           (remainder k n)))))
```